# Why is the name of the user is not being shown instead of the Login icon in the menu bar after a successful login?

Tags: authentication, react-hooks, navbar, logout

So I have an issue where I set up the frontend so that when the user logs in, the Login button in the menu bar will change to display the user's name currently logged in with a drop-down list showing both the user profile and logout buttons. But every time I'm logging in with a user, the Login in the menu bar does not change, and even though in the console it says that the user has logged in, I can still go back to the login screen and log in again.

Below is the code:

**Navbar**

```js
function Navbar() {
  const [showLinks, setShowLinks] = useState(false);
  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { cart, userInfo } = state;

  const handleLogout = () => {
    ctxDispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGOUT' });
    localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
  };
console.log(userInfo);
```

```js
<div className="rightSide">
        <div className="linksTwo">
         {/* {userInfo ? (
            <NavDropdown id="nav-dropdown-light" title= {userInfo.name}>
              <LinkContainer to="/profile">
                <NavDropdown.Item> User Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
              </LinkContainer>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <Link
                className="dropdown-item"
                to="#logout"
                onClick={handleLogout}
              >
                {' '}
                Logout
              </Link>
            </NavDropdown>
          ) : ( */}
            <Link to="/login">
              Login <LoginIcon />
            </Link>
         {/* )} */}
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Login**

```js
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Store } from '../components/Store';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { getError } from '../utils';

export default function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const redirectInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get('redirect');
  const redirect = redirectInUrl ? redirectInUrl : '/profile';

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;

  function validateForm() {
    return email.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!password) {
      toast.warn('Password is not correct');
      return;
    }
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/users/login', {
        email,
        password,
      });
      ctxDispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGIN', payload: data });
      localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
      navigate(redirect || '/profile');
      toast.success(email + ' has logged in successfully');
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(getError(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container className="small-container">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Login</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Login</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            autoComplete="on"
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="m-3">
          <Button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-outline-success me-2"
            disabled={!validateForm()}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className="m-3">
          New customer? <Link to={`/register`}>Register a new account</Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: You say userInfo is valorized in console.log, but where are you logging it ? Are you sure NavBar is in the same tree of your Context.Provider ? If console.log(userInfo) is placed in NavBar, before return statement, and it shows a rerender when you log in and userInfo receives data there, then it has to work.

Comment: @CesarePolonara - I tried the console.log(userInfo) before the return statement and in the console it states: "undefined". Does that mean the Navbar component is not in the same tree as the Context.Provider? If so how would I go about to make sure that it is please? The "userInfo" is being logged in a component called Store.jsx.

Here is the code for that component: https://pastebin.com/BWdMiygc

Comment: I made an answer since I think you are just destructuring your context in a bad way in Navbar.

Comment: @CesarePolonara - So I tried what you suggested in the answer, I also edited my original post to show this, now the issue is different. When I made the change it rerendered the data in the console but it also gave me another error as shown in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/O8DL9WG.jpg

What I did was I commented out the "{userInfo ? ( till the ") : (" also included in the edit of my original post and the error was gone and now when I retry to login I get "undefined undefined and the data".

Comment: An update regarding the above, I managed to get it to show the drop down even though the name of the user currently logged in is not being shown and when I click on the drop down I get the User Profile and the Logout buttons.

This is how it currently looks: https://i.imgur.com/yXTghqs.jpg

Comment: I managed to figure out what was causing the name not being shown in the menu bar and now it is fixed. Thanks for your help @CesarePolonara! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Login component you are doing:

```
  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
```

In Navbar Component you are doing:

```
  const { state, userInfo, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
```

I ***guess*** that you are just destructuring your context bad in Navbar, try:

```
const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
const { userInfo } = state;
```

Or you could also abbreviate it in : 
`const { state: { userInfo }, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);`